# PHP Cronjob Why doesn't this OAuth request POST my twitter status

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have a quite specific question here.
I have been working with Cronjobs to get my Twittermessages automatically POSTed. I found the OAuth library by Abraham Williams.

This is what I did so far on my setup:

```
require_once ('Abraham/TwitterOAuth/autoloader.php');
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumerKey        = "XXXXX"; //add the key from your app
$consumerSecret     = "XXXXX"; //add the secret from your app
$accessToken        = "XXXXX"; //add the access token from your app
$accessSecret       = "XXXXX"; //add the access secret from your app
$message            = "This is another Test";

$connection         = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$accessToken,$accessSecret);

$connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => $message));
```

My question is here. If I load this into my browser, shouldn't this already automatically send a Tweet?

I have setup my own Twitter app and I also set all permissions to read and write.

Comment: Well, what happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but there are also no Tweets sent out when I check on Twitter. I assume the script does nothing right now.

Comment: You should be getting either tweets or errors. Add something like 'echo 'test';` after the `post()` call and see if it gets output. If it doesn't, check your server logs or turn on error_reporting.

Comment: I get an output for echo 'test'; So no error message.

Comment: Do a `print_r` of the results of `post()`. It should give you a response, likely with a post ID and possibly a link. Maybe you're posting to a different account than you expect.

Comment: like this? 
print_r $connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => $message));

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: OK, here we go

Line 16: print_r $connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => $message));

Result: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/nextleve/www/www/admin/cronjobs/social.php on line 16

Comment: `print_r()`, not `print_r`. http://php.net/print_r Very useful for debugging.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification:

This is what I got.

stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32 [message] => Could not authenticate you. ) ) )

Comment: " Could not authenticate you" i think that explains all

Comment: Works now. Missing character for one of the Tokens. Thanks alot!!!